# are clones siblings to the original?

Tags: genetics

i have a question about cloning, if a person had his/her DNA sample like hair or blood used to make a clone wouldn't that clone be that same person's brother or sister since they share the same genetic makeup? also, what if a person had heterozygous genes and had two clones? but the clones had their alleles swapped making one clone have most of that person's dominant genes while the other had that person's recessive genes making the clones homozygous, would that make the person a father of mother to those clones or a blood related brother or sister?

Answer (score 1):

This actually isn't a biology question, it's a moral, legal and semantic question. "Siblings", biologically, are offspring of the same parent(s). A clone, as developed through human technology, isn't the offspring of any parent in the usual sense. It was not generated from a pair of gametes that came from two different parents; it came about via a completely different biological process, one that doesn't really occur in nature (there are many natural processes that result in identical copies we call "clones", but none of these does exactly the same thing as technological process we call "cloning").

Biologically, a clone is a clone, siblings are siblings, and they come about via very different processes.

None of this means that **legally**, or **morally**, or **by the dictionary definition**, we cannot redefine "sibling" to include clones. And it makes perfect sense to do so. It could also make sense to define clones as "offspring" instead. This could be based on genetic similarity, or on other things.

The thing is, there isn't an obvious single answer to how they *should* be redefined if human cloning were a thing. This isn't an issue human society has had to deal with yet so none of these redefinitions have happened.

For an idea of what they could look like though, I'm reminded of Lois McMaster Bujold's science-fiction Vorkosigan series, that deals with cloning (in books like *Brothers in Arms* in particular). Different societies in her books deal with cloning in different ways, and human clones have different statuses. One of those societies (one of the more sensible ones) considers a clone to be the child of the cloned person if it's an adult cloning themselves to make a baby, but to be the sibling of the cloned person if the person's parents decided to clone their child. Basically, in that society the people who decided to make the clone would be considered its parents, and the clone's genetics would have nothing to do with it.

Note that even in our society, siblings and parents aren't only defined by genetic similarity or any biological process, but by a legal relationship, shared history and responsibilities. Adoptive parents and siblings are considered in many (most? all?) countries to be legally equivalent to biological parents and siblings.

Comment: but you just said "A clone, as developed through human technology, isn't the offspring of any parent in the usual sense." then said "It could also make sense to define clones as "offspring" instead." so would a clone be a sibling or offspring to the original? also, to be a sibling to a clone is exactly what i meant if someone was cloned off of since it's that same person's DNA being replicated.

Comment: @sarahdan I am saying that right now, there is no definition of "sibling" or "offspring" that includes clones. My second paragraph was about *how we might change the definitions* to include clones, but I can't tell you in advance what the governments, ethics commissions, supreme courts and people of the world will change them to if human cloning happens, because that hasn't happened yet. Do you understand what I mean by this not being a biological question? Adoptive siblings are siblings but that has nothing to do with biology, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: i agree, but i can't help but feel that if you were cloned you and your clone would be siblings since you share the same genetic code.

Comment: @sarahdan to put my answer differently, your question seems to assume that "siblings" and "parents" are defined by genetic similarity. But this is not true. Parents and siblings are defined by *how an individual came to exist*. If it was formed from the union of two gametes, the organisms the gametes came from are its parents. If other organisms came from the union of gametes from those same parents, they are siblings. All other systems for making new organisms involve extending the definitions or using new words.

Comment: @sarahsan in nature plenty of organisms reproduce by making copies that share the exact same genetic code, and those are usually referred to as "parent" and "offspring" but it depends on context. They are also sometimes seen as parts of a same, larger clonal organism. So you see "same genetic code" doesn't mean "siblings". You assume that because *in humans*, the only people with identical genes are twins, who are siblings by the standard definition (children of the same parents). But humans don't reproduce by cloning, so we have no words or definitions for the relationships between clones.

Comment: @sarahdan and the fact that twins are the only humans that have identical genes, *and* happen to be siblings, is pure coincidence. If humans could reproduce asexually we might think it normal for children to have the exact same genes as their parents.

Comment: but that would be kinda weird to define something that has the same genetic makeup as you as your kid. i mean, if the two pair of chromosomes you have was used to create another being, surely the product of that would be your sibling like how you explained if a parent were to clone a kid they already have their current kid would have a sibling that was cloned off him/her.

Comment: @sarahsan why would it be weird? It's exactly what we do with aphids when they reproduce through parthogenesis. When we talk about a cell asexually splitting into two cells, we talk about the new cells being daughter cells, not sister cells. Why would it make sense for something that has the same genetic makeup as you to be your sibling? Human siblings don't typically have the same genetic makeup, anymore than human parents and children do.

Comment: yeah i know asexual is normal but cloning like ding somatic cell transfer seems to come off more as something where your genetic material such as hair, skin, or blood consisting of your entire two chromosomes to make a clone would be the end result of you and your clone come off as siblings, thats what i wonder.

Comment: @sarahsan ...why would cloning make people more like siblings than asexual reproduction does? I mean, do you actually "wonder" here or do you think the answer is "yes" and you're just fishing for confirmation? If not, how exactly have I not answered your question here? Just repeating the question won't help.

Comment: i said somatic cell transfer, in other words, EX: you take hair from a person named tom and a egg from a person named samantha who donates her egg but has her sex cells removed from it making it be a nucleus that holds tom's hair to make a clone, after undergoing the process, an embryo is formed and placed in samantha to give birth to the said clone. (this is what i'm talking about wondering if the clone is an actual sibling of tom)

Comment: and just to be clear, you did say in order for a clone to be a sibling to the original the original has to be cloned by the parents, but isn't this the same thing?

Comment: @sarahsan again, why does somatic cell transfer say "sibling" to you? Human siblings don't come from somatic cell transfer. Please answer my questions instead of just repeating yourself. And I did NOT say that "in order for a clone to be a sibling of the original the original has to be cloned from the parents". Please read what I write more carefully. It sounds like you're confusing something I said about an IMAGINARY law in a SCIENCE-FICTION book with an actual statement about reality, and that's not even what the imaginary law I mentioned said.

Comment: @sarahsan actually for a direct example of somatic cell transfer not resulting in something people called "siblings", Dolly the sheep's DNA donor was generally referred to as her mother.

Comment: i already gave my answer as to why somatic cell transfer is saying "sibling" to me you should read carefully, and i'll say it again more clearly, the reason why i see somatic cell transfer as a cloning process to where the original being cloned off of is a sibling, it's cause like identical twins they themselves are close to that of being clones, but naturally different from cloning, but most of all in this case, it's because of two beings sharing the EXACT DNA structure should/could be that of siblings since there are no shared 23 chromosomes/sex cells between two people.

Comment: @sarahsan that is true, all those are things you've said, and not only did I read them at the time, I addressed every one of them so I don't know what you are looking for here. Except for the twins thing, which you haven't brought up before but I also addressed (though I could add that one difference between twins and clones that affects how they "come off" is that twins are always the same age & from the same pregnancy, clones not). Do you still have a biological question that needs to be answered here, or do you just have an opinion on how words should be used that you want me to agree with?